# Datatable Add Column Error

Tags: c#, list, datatable

Iam created for loop for inserting column names in my datatables

```
public static string matchHEADER(string filename, List<FlatFileLookUp> myitem)
{
for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= myitem.Count - 1; cnt++ )
    { 
        dt1.Columns.Add(myitem[cnt].standard.ToString(), typeof(String));
    }
}
```

it throws error:

**A column named \u0027EmpId\u0027 already belongs to this DataTable.**

```
myitem datas
[0] = EmpID
[1] = NTID
[2] = FirstName
[3] = LastName
[...] = ....
```

I checked every data in myitem[cnt].standard.ToString(). They are different. How can i fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide content of `myitem` list? At least all values of `standard` property

Comment: But you are reusing a global variable (dt1). This could be a problem if you call this code two times. The columns added in the first loop could be still there and adding them again will trigger the problem. Can you Clear the columns collection?

Comment: Already updated my post,

Comment: @Steve I dont know what variable is global in my code. Can you point out what variable is it?

Comment: @EnzoZow do `dt1.Columns.Clear();` at first line of this method

Comment: @Steve Thank you. It works now